# Network Signal in android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem I have to show signal strength in an app. Just like as our mobile shows towers for poor signal strength it only shows one tower and for good signal strength, it shows all towers.

In the same way, I also want to calculate the signal strength.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phone State Listener which gives you the signal strength. First of all, define globally.

```
var telephonyManager: TelephonyManager? = null
var psListener: MyPhoneStateListener? = null
```

then initialize the telephony manager and listen to the changes in the network.

```
psListener = MyPhoneStateListener()
            telephonyManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            telephonyManager!!.listen(psListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS)
```

After creating a class that extends PhoneStateListener, you can make this class an inner in Kotlin. As below

```
inner  class MyPhoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener() {
            var signalSupport = 0
            override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength) {
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength)
    
                if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
                    signalSupport = signalStrength.gsmSignalStrength
                    Log.d("signal", "------ gsm signal --> $signalSupport")
                    if (signalSupport > 30) {
                        Log.d("signal", "Signal GSM : Good")
                    } else if (signalSupport in 21..29) {
                        Log.d("signal", "Signal GSM : Avarage")
                    } else if (signalSupport in 4..19) {
                        Log.d("signal", "Signal GSM : Weak")
                    } else if (signalSupport < 3) {
                        Log.d("signal", "Signal GSM : Very weak")
                    }
                } else {
                    signalSupport = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
                }
                signalStrengthValue = signalSupport.toString()
            }
        }
```

this signal strength value variable is hold the data of signal strength

Comment: you don't mention which sdk you use, because on Android 12 using sdk 33 most of the things you use are deprecated.